# Selection of pods in Kubernetes NodePort service type

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-nodeport

As per my understanding, NodePort service types in Kubernetes opens a port at node level through which external clients can access specific pods.

I would like to clarify one point regarding this.
Assume a scenario where I deploy one service with 10 replicas, and all these 10 pods are placed in a single worker node. As I expose this service as NodePort, how the Kubernetes select the pods from available 10 pods in the same Node?

I assume k8s cannot simply map NodePort to actual port, as multiples ports are running in the same node.
Is there a mechanism to select pods here? Or am I missing some basics here?

Comment: Whichever node you contact externally, the Service will be able to reach a Pod on any node; it doesn't matter whether they're all packed on to the same Node or not.  The Service internally acts as a load balancer and in practice you might find it round-robins between replicas.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In K8s, when you expose a svc as type `NodePort`, it opens a port on all nodes in the cluster. Regardless of whether multiple replicas of the service are on the same node, K8s handles incoming traffic on the `NodePort` efficiently by internally load balancing it to any pod associated with the svc. This ensures high availability and scalability without being affected by pod placement.